# use of undeclared identifier 'a'

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program like this, but the compiler keeps reporting the error that it fails to understand the identifier 'a'. Could someone please tell me what goes wrong here?
  Here is the code and the error:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
   char buffer[200];
   memset(buffer,’a’,200);
   int fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR );
   write(fd, buffer, 200);
   lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
   read(fd, buffer, 100);
   lseek(fd, 500, SEEK_CUR);
   write(fd, buffer, 100);
}

/Users/messfish/Desktop/os1.c:9:18: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed
outside of literals and identifiers
   memset(buffer,’a’,200);
                 ^
/Users/messfish/Desktop/os1.c:9:22: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed
  outside of literals and identifiers
   memset(buffer,’a’,200);
                   ^
/Users/messfish/Desktop/os1.c:9:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
   memset(buffer,’a’,200);
```

I use the **gcc** as the compiler.

Comment: You are using the wrong single quote around the `a`. You should type ***`'a'`*** rather than copy/paste it.

Comment: You would do well to check return values for errors, especially from `open`, `read`, and `write`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong type of quotes, possibly because you copy-pasted it from somewhere. Instead of

```
’a’
```

You want

```
'a'
```